# Как записать данные в  Excel файл?

Tags: c#, excel

Не завися при этом от версии Excel.

Пытался пользоваться одной [библиотекой](http://mymemoryjob.blogspot.com/2011/04/c-excel-com.html) , но файл не открывается, пишет не валидный.
Пробовал вот [отсюда](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-tutorial.htm) но тоже с ошибками.
Может есть у кого рабочий пример?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мы обычно используем ADO.NET для работы с Excel.

Но это не для формирования произвольного Excel-документа, а для заливки данных в диапазоны.

С помощью `adodb` можно получить экземпляр `Recordset` и через него работать с отдельными ячейками Excel.

Формат строки подключения для создания `OleDbConnection`:

`Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\"{0}\";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"`

В месте {0} подставить путь к файлу Excel.

Работа с `adodb`:

```
  Connection ado_cn = new Connection();
  ado_cn.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0";
  ado_cn.Open(string.Format("Data Source=\"{0}\"; Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"", this.FileName), "", "", 0);
ado_cn.BeginTrans();

Recordset rs = new Recordset();
rs.Open("SELECT * FROM MyRange", ado_cn, CursorTypeEnum.adOpenForwardOnly, LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic, 0); // Получаем Recordset, связанный с диапазоном MyRange

while (!rs.EOF) // Обходим строки Recordset
{
  foreach (string colName in sourceData) // Какие-то исходные колонки
    rs.Fields[colName].Value = someValue; // Пишем какие-то данные в ячейки диапазона

  rs.MoveNext(); // Переходим на следующую строку
}
rs.Close(); // Всё закрываем
ado_cn.CommitTrans();
ado_cn.Close();
```

Ещё один вариант - генерировать xml для Excel. Это не xlsx, а очень старый формат, начала 90-х. Он довольно простой.

Answer (score 0):

[Раннее связывание](http://wladm.narod.ru/C_Sharp/comexcel.html)

[Позднее связывание](http://www.realcoding.net/article/view/2709)

Есть еще способ генерировать с помощью OpenXML, но такие документы может открвать только Office начиная с 2007, если я ничего не путаю.