# Загрузить DataTable в файл Excel по частям. C#, ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

Я использую ClosedXML.Excel для создания файла Excel из DataTable. Но если в DataTable хранится очень много записей (например миллион строк), то приложение закрывается с ошибкой памяти. Как мне переделать функцию создания Excel файла так, чтобы я мог загружать строки из DataTable в Excel файл по частям (по 10000 записей например). Моя функция для создания Excel файла выглядит так:

```
public static void DataTableToExcelClosedXML(DataTable dt, string filePath, string fileName)
{
    XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook();
    wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, fileName);
    wb.SaveAs(filePath);
}
```

Comment: Можно попробовать посмотреть под рефлектором метод заполнения ячеек из библиотеки ClosedXML, создать класс с необходимым для работы содержимым и переопределить метод заполнения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смог добиться хорошей производительности при 1000000+ записей при помощи библиотеки EPPlus.

Функция конвертации DataTable в файл xlsx с разбиением по листам:

```
public static void DataTableToXLSX(DataTable dt, string filePath, string sheetName)
        {
            using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(filePath)))
            {
                if (dt.Rows.Count < 1000000)
                {
                    ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheetName);
                    ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);
                    pck.Save();
                }
                else
                {
                    int listCount = 0;

                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i += 1000000)
                    {
                        DataTable buf = dt.Clone();

                        listCount++;
                        for (int j = i; j < i + 1000000 && j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
                        {
                            buf.ImportRow(dt.Rows[i]);
                        }
                        ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheetName + " " + listCount);
                        ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(buf, true);
                        pck.Save();
                    }
                }
            }
            Process.Start(filePath);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Посоветую подключить `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` и `Interop.Microsoft.Office.Core`

и сам код:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
...
public static export(DataTable dt)
{
  Excel.Application objExcel = new Excel.Application();
  Excel.Workbook workbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add();
  Excel.Worksheet sheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;  
  Excel.Range range = sheet.Range[sheet.Cells[1, 1], sheet.Cells[ct.Rows.Count, ct.Columns.Count]];
  for (int i=0; i< ct.Rows.Count; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < ct.Columns.Count; ++j)
      range.Cells[1+i, 1+j] = ct.Rows[i][j].ToString();
  sheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
  sheet.Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit();
  sheet.PageSetup.Orientation = Excel.XlPageOrientation.xlLandscape;
  sheet.PageSetup.Zoom = false;
  sheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1;
  sheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = false;
  sheet.PageSetup.ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = true;
  sheet.PageSetup.AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = true;
  objExcel.Visible = true;
}
```

Можно [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/90772/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-excel-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB?rq=1)

Comment: Я думаю подключать excel в веб приложении будет не очень хорошо.

Comment: @mirypoko попробуйте OpenXML или Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0

Answer (score 0):

1. Для полноценной работы с файлами MS Office из .Net стоит воспользоваться библиотекой Open XML SDK 2.5 for Microsoft Office. Обязательно используйте Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool - генератор .Net кода по готовым файлам.
   В генерируемом коде разобраться несложно.
   Таким образом вы сможете создавать любые файлы MS Office без костылей в виде ActiveX автомации, медлительного межпроцессного маршаллига данных, потребности устанавливать офис на сервер.
2. Второй способ которым я часто злоупотребляю - написание кода на VBA с использованием ADODB, это работает тоже очень быстро.